# How to Deploy AutoCad .Net dll?

Tags: c#, dll, deployment, autocad-plugin

I have developed a plugin to automate some work in AutoCAD using C# and AutoCAD managed API references. while adding reference in project, I have provided absolute path of accoremgd.dll,acdbmgd.dll,acmgd.dll from AutoCAD installation folder. how can I give these references in deployment as we can't copy these dlls ? how will I use my result dll plugin on other's system ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about those references, you just deploy your dll. Assuming that your users have AutoCad installed, all the dlls that your project references reside in the same directory as `acad.exe` and will be automatically visible to the application. For this reason, the fact that your project targets the dlls in a specific location does not matter.

To deploy, it will work very much the same way as it does on your system. You just need to set up auto-loading. Basically, two of the best options is to either use the registry or use one of `acad.lsp` or `acaddoc20xx.lsp` to NETLOAD your dll on startup. [This article](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-autoload-DLLs-with-AutoCAD.html) will guide you through both techniques. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46395466/7159784) and others in the thread.

Comment: needn't mess with the registry if using the autoloader - just create a .bundle folder with a PackageContents.xml file and dump the contents of your dlls in there and voila it should all work!

Comment: I created a video and a short reference guide: it's here for anyone interested: https://benkoshy.github.io/2022/11/14/how-to-deploy.autocad-dll-visual-studio-setup.html

Answer (score 1):

> I have developed a plugin to automate some work in AutoCAD using C# and AutoCAD managed API references. while adding reference in project, I have provided absolute path of accoremgd.dll,acdbmgd.dll,acmgd.dll from AutoCAD installation folder. how can I give these references in deployment as we can't copy these dlls ?

As mentioned above the references will be added when you deploy your dll as long as the path to the installation folder remains the same on your client's machine.

> how will I use my result dll plugin on other's system ?

There are a few different ways to do this some of which have already been mentioned. The best way to do this is probably using the .bundle format. You can find more documentation about that here https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/AutoCAD-Customization/files/GUID-40F5E92C-37D8-4D54-9497-CD9F0659F9BB-htm.html

Basically it works by creating a folder with the name `YourPlugin.bundle` and in the folder you have a `PackageContents.xml` that tells AutoCAD how to load and run your project.